# How to unit test a route with a bean which will access DB?

Tags: java, apache-camel

Here DB is just an example. It means something can't be prepared in unit test environment.

Consider the route below:

```
DBBean dbBean = new DBBean();
from("direct:test").bean(dbBean).to("direct:someOtherLogic");
```

When do unit test, is there any approach to mock the 'dbBean'? In unit test, it's hard to set up a real DB.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Camel has a test kit, which allows you to manipulate the route before being tested. Then you can keep the route untouched, and then replace parts of the route, and whatnot. Its a bit elaborate, and its documented as the advice-with functionality here: http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html

It generally works easier if the EIPs have IDs assigned, as you can then refer to those ids, and replace it with something else.

However if you know that you want to replace the first BeanDefinition you can do:

```
weaveByType(BeanDefinition.class).selectFirst().replace().to("mock:dbBean");
```

See the above links how to use this with the advice-with in the Camel Test Kit (eg camel-test) JAR.

Mind that its recommended to tell Camel Test Kit that you are using advice with, which you do as documented in the bottom of that link.

Answer (score 2):

you can use an embedded database (DERBY, etc)...here is an example taken from a [camel-jdbc unit test](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-jdbc/src/test/resources/org/apache/camel/component/jdbc/camelContext.xml)

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="timer://kickoff?period=10000"/>
        <setBody>
           <constant>select * from customer</constant>
        </setBody>
        <to uri="jdbc:testdb"/>
        <to uri="mock:result"/>
    </route>
 </camelContext>

  <!-- Just add a demo to show how to bind a date source for camel in Spring-->
  <jdbc:embedded-database id="testdb" type="DERBY">
      <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/init.sql"/>
  </jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Otherwise, you might try using [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) (to setup test database) or [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) (to mock the response of a DB call)

Comment: Good solution for DB unit test. However, for some other beans, it maybe hard to simulate the environment. I think mocking the bean is a better approach.

Comment: yep, I understand completely...Mockito is awesome if you can get it to play nice with your setup...otherwise, Claus suggested some other approaches (advicewith, etc) that would work as well...good luck

Answer (score 1):

If your DbBean is an interface, then you can have 2 different implementations. One for the real DB work. And other for mocked unit tests, where you simulate the DB.

Then its just a matter of instantiating a mock in your unit test

```
DbBean db = new MockDbBean()
```

As its just plain Java code. You can have a getter/setter in your RouteBuilder class

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    private DbBean dbBean;

    // getter/setter for dbBean

   public void configure() throws Exception {
      from("direct:test").bean(dbBean).to("direct:someOtherLogic");
   }
}
```

Then from an unit test its just a matter of setting the MockDbBean using a setter on MyRouteBuilder instance.

Comment: So I think the key is expose the bean in route to outside. When do unit test, set the mock bean into the route tested. But is there any way to fetch the bean directly from camel context and replace it by a mock bean? In this way, I don't need to modify current route and no more field and getter/setter are needed.